# get manager SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am new to SharePoint and could use some help as I have been thrown into the deep end without any flotation device.

I am creating a 'Leave application system' with workflows; when employee applies for leave their manager must auto select and email sent to their managers.  However I can not find a way to do this, I was told to use the CallHTTP web service but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone give an example of how I can do this?  I am using SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you can create a quite simple one with a calendar and a approval workflow which start an approval process and send a email notification to the manager.

A simple start point:https://o365.co.uk/sharepoint-online-holiday-request-system/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fr-waeizkQ0

And of course there are already solutions you can have a check:https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380880?tab=Overview

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple approval process if the requester provides the manager's email or it is a dropdown menu coming for a multiple-choice column. it can be implemented by SharePoint designer. Please follow this guide. 
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-32c9c0bf-5e20-4f74-8b9c-d3ea79f2962b

You mentioned that you need to use CallHTTP web services, I am assuming that it is a custom solution and using SharePoint on-premise and it requires a good understanding of WCF, Asp.net as well as how to consume this service by using CSOM model. here is a good example:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx